# Questions regarding on-screen keyboard app development

Tags: keyboard, application-development

I am volunteering some of my time to help get my favorite keyboard ported to Ubuntu, and I wanted to check with the community to see what approach to use for this kind of app.  Are there any special API features to deal with keyboard apps?  Are there any decent tutorials or is the code for the current on-screen keyboard available for me to study?

I'm an embedded developer with no real mobile or desktop application experience, but I have fooled around with GTK+ and I've done some work with VB6 on Windows.  I spend most of my time in C.  I'm basically just looking for some direction in what to look into to get started/making sure I don't waste time trying to use the wrong tools for the job.

They are basically asking me to get a simple skeleton running to place a keyboard image, gather touch input, and write to the current focus.  Considering that this keyboard is simply the ***best*** way to input text on a touch screen I want to do it justice in properly porting it to the new convergent platform.

I greatly appreciate any advice I can get.

---

If you're curious, the keyboard I speak of is MessagEase.  They hold the current world record for *unassisted*(no dictionary lookup) touchscreen typing speed at 100 words per minute.  All letters, numbers, and symbols are mapped to the primary keyboard (no switching required).  They have been providing the keyboard on Android and iOS for free for years, and they are now trying to target smartwatches.  They have constantly added new features to the keyboard and have never asked for money until a recent Indiegogo campaign.  My assistance is my way of showing my appreciation.  It is also somewhat selfish, because as much as I love Ubuntu I will **never** even consider using a touchscreen device that does not support MessagEase: it is truly that much better.